# HTML5 Canvas gradient appears black

Tags: html

I'm trying to reproduce the following background image in an HTML5 canvas, however what renders on the browser is a black box. The original image was made in illustrator and that's where I'm getting the coordinates from (actually used an export plug-in).

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>index</title>
  <script>

    function init() {

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      draw(ctx);
    }

    function draw(ctx) {

      var gradient;

      // layer1/Red Background Bottom
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(1036.0, 789.7);
      ctx.lineTo(12.0, 789.7);
      ctx.lineTo(12.0, 21.7);
      ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 21.7);
      ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 789.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(235, 10, 10)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Shadow Bottom
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(1036.0, 788.7);
      ctx.lineTo(12.0, 788.7);
      ctx.lineTo(12.0, 20.7);
      ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 20.7);
      ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 788.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.save();
      ctx.transform(3.200, 0.000, 0.000, -4.206, 196.6, -5329.4);
      gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(96.7, -1580.0, 0.0, 96.7, -1580.0, 161.7);
      gradient.addColorStop(0.00, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
      gradient.addColorStop(0.55, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
      gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="1049" height="792"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Actually I just realized that I forgot to add the Alphas in the gradient stops, the change below solves the problem:

```
      gradient.addColorStop(0.00, "rgba(0, 0, 0,0)");
      gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the gradient stops..

```
 gradient.addColorStop(0.00, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
 gradient.addColorStop(0.55, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
 gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
```

They are all black (red 0, green 0, blue 0). Changing the values to ...

```
gradient.addColorStop(0.00, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.55, "rgb(125, 0, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
```

Gives you full red in centre (0) (red 255, green 0, blue 0)
half red in middle (.55) (red 125, green 0, blue 0)
and no red (black) at the edge (1.00) (red 0, green 0, blue 0)

Then you just have to change the centre point of your gradient.

```js
function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {
  var gradient;

  // layer1/Red Background Bottom
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(1036.0, 789.7);
  ctx.lineTo(12.0, 789.7);
  ctx.lineTo(12.0, 21.7);
  ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 21.7);
  ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 789.7);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(235, 10, 10)";
  ctx.fill();

  // layer1/Shadow Bottom
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(1036.0, 788.7);
  ctx.lineTo(12.0, 788.7);
  ctx.lineTo(12.0, 20.7);
  ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 20.7);
  ctx.lineTo(1036.0, 788.7);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.transform(3.200, 0.000, 0.000, -4.206, 196.6, -5329.4);
  gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(96.7, -1380.0, 0.0, 96.7, -1580.0, 261.7);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.00, "rgb(250, 0, 0)");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.55, "rgb(125, 0, 0)");
  gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgb(50, 0, 0)");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1049" height="792"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Note in my code that I'm also drawing a red rect right underneath the gradient rect. All the gradient stops are black, but their Alpha changes from 0 to 1 (it's a radial grayscale transparency). So the red underneath the gradually transparent part of the gradient should be visible. Actually these exact same gradient stops produce in Illustrator the image in my original post. Changing them to the values proposed here, produces a result different to the desired image.

Comment: Actually I just realized that I forgot to specify the Alphas, for example the last gradient stop becomes `gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 51)");`